# YouTube API - get next related video

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I'm building an accessible site for disabled students to watch YouTube independently. Currently using jsapi to control the player (play/pause/volume) but I need to create a link for the NEXT related video.

Is there a method to get the link/video ID for the video that YouTube states is 'up next' to make this screen reader friendly.

note: this is not using playlists - so it's the link that YouTube decides is the next related one

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Related_videos_feed

This is the feed to find the "related" video for a specific video. You should be able to do continuous play using this feed.

Comment: Hadn't thought of using a feed for this - should work OK. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

curl "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/DZtvQeW3aR8/related?v=2&alt=jsonc"

where DZtvQeW3aR8 is the videoid

Answer (score 0):

As YouTube API v2.0 got deprecated you can now use this v3.0 method to get the same functionality:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-related-videos